# Is it possible to remove turn limits in multi-player games?

Tags: civilization-5

I've started a game with my friends. However, mid-way through the game, we noticed a turn limit (after saving the game for resuming later).
The odd thing though, is I never opted to enforce one (in the game creation screen).

## Question:

Is there any way I can remove the turn limit so that we can play on?
Right now, the limit is 333 turns (of which we're already at turn 120).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You won't be able to change it now that the game is started. The option is set at the start of a game, in the advanced options, there's a `Max turns` settings.

Setting it at 0 will remove the turns limit of a game. [Source from Steam](https://steamcommunity.com/app/65980/discussions/0/619569341137914262/#p3)

Linked page 3 as it is the page with the most important information on how to see that 0 is the proper value and this is from page 4 :

> 1) First game. Set up game, advanced options. Max Turns option was NOT checked (this appears to be the games default configuration unless you change it). Disabled all victory conditions. Started game, checked game details from menu, it listed "Time" as a victory condition (peculiar, but proceeded nonetheless). On Turn 400 the game abruptly ended (was playing vs 1 AI on easy, i was just ending turns over and over not doing anything... and again, all victory options were turned off). Game abruptly ends with the "Time" ending (shows the box art screen, a brief voice over about time running out, game ends)
>
> 2) 2nd game. Set up game, advanced options. Max Turns checked on, set to 0 turns. All victory coniditions disabled, otherwise identical settings as last game. After 560 turns the game was / is still continuing with no end in sight, game doesn't appear to end at turn 400 as the previous game did.. thus this worked.

Comment: I've heard that you may be able to remove turn timers (or ultimately edit player information) while a game is running with the Faraxis Turner (found in the Civ V SDK), but I'll investigate before accepting.

Comment: Didn't know about the tuner, it looks like it is possible according to [civfanatics.com](http://forums.civfanatics.com/showthread.php?t=401194) but no one has posted on how. And can't find anything on the turner to turn it off while the game has started.

Answer (score 6):

I made a simple web app that will let you change the game parameters of a save file, including max turns: [Civilization V save editor](https://bmaupin.github.io/civ5save-editor/)

Just open your save file in the app and uncheck *Time victory* (it will automatically set *Max turns* to 0). Then download the save file with the changes and open it in the game.